# Approximation of probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following pdf, known as the Beckmann distribution:

$$f_r(r) = \frac{r}{2 \pi \sigma_x \sigma_y} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}{\exp\left(-\frac{(r \cos \phi - \mu_x)^2}{2 \sigma_x^2} - \frac{(r \sin \phi - \mu_y)^2}{2 \sigma_y^2}\right) d\phi}$$

I'm using this pdf for a certain derivation and in its current form (integral form), the derivation is quite complex. I was wondering if there exists methods in the literature that enables me to approximate it by a parametric pdf that has a nicer form.